# error type: fuzzer.c:26:25: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

Tags: c

Although I think I have more than one issue in this code, I want to solve my compiler error first.  Thank you in advance for any suggestions.  I will try to address run errors next.
The Error:

```
fuzzer.c: In function ‘main’:
fuzzer.c:26:25: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  charArray[arraySize-1] = NULL;  /*make sure charArray[] is a string array that has a size of arraySize */
                         ^
```

The Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{

        int fuzzNum = 100;
        char buffer[1000], *charArray;
        int status, ret, i, j, retCode, arraySize; /* */
        time_t t;
        FILE *fin;
        FILE *fout;

        srand((unsigned) time(&t));  /* randomize the initial seed */

  for(i=0; i<fuzzNum; i++)
  {

        charArray = (char *) malloc(arraySize);
        for (j=0; j< arraySize; j++)
        charArray[j] = 'A';
        charArray[arraySize-1] = NULL;  
         /*make sure charArray[] is a string array that has a size of arraySize */


        /* open and read the cross.jpg file as a binary format file*/
        fin=fopen("./cross.jpg","rb" );

        /*generate a variable file name*/
                char fileName[30]; int n;

                sprintf(fileName, "crashed-%d.jpg", n);
        fout=fopen("./test.jpg","wb");

        /* execute the jpg2bmp file to process the test.jpg file*/
        char comBuf[200];
        sprintf(comBuf, "./jpg2bmp test.jpg temp.bmp");
        ret=system(comBuf);

        free(charArray); /* must free memory for repeat testing! */

        ret=system(buffer);
        wait(&status);
        retCode=WEXITSTATUS(ret);

        if ( retCode == 128+11 || retCode ==128+6) /* segmentation fault (11) or Abort (6) */
        {
          printf("retCode=%d, arraySize = %d", retCode, arraySize);
          fflush(stdout);  /*make sure output is print out immediately ! */
        }

  }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `charArray[arraySize-1] = NULL;` --> `charArray[arraySize-1] = 0;`. Also `arraySize` is uninitialized.

Comment: First of, this is a warning, not an error. Second, why not just `charArray[arraySize-1] = 0;`?.

Comment: charArray isn't a string array that has a size of arraySize, because charArray isn't a string array. It's a char array (hence the name).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is a warning, and not an error. Your code should compile successfully in the least, if this warning is the only issue the compiler produces during the build process. However, if you want to overcome this issue, you can simply change:

```
charArray[arraySize-1] = NULL;
```

To:

```
charArray[arraySize-1] = 0;
```

While `charArray` is a pointer that points to the first memory space in the array, `charArray[i]`, where `i` represents a counter as an example here, is of data type `int`. Now, `NULL` is used when a pointer points to nothing, or in computer terms, to the ground. Therefore, the compiler warns you that you are storing a pointer attribute in a non-pointer memory space (Sorry for the really por choice of words, if there is anything wrong with it, please correct me in the comments box).

The above code change should resolve the warning your compiler produces.